# toggle button doesn't remain in its state

Tags: android, alarmmanager, togglebutton

```
my list view has some toggle button and dates which is to be checked and uncheck on the basis of user choice 
the functionality is to set alarm for those days when button is checked

when i am clicking the toggle button it sets the alarm for the day 
but when i click next button it overwrite it
 **for ex ... let the user has choice to set alarm for  1, 2 3, 4 or all dates and individual toggle button for this if the user has selected 1, 4,5 then it will work for 5 not for all
one more issue which i am unable to figure out is when i scroll the list view and the checked button get disappear it automatically sets it unchecked**
```

- for some reason i cannot put the code

  public class DDListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

  ```
      ArrayList<DataModelDD> listArray;
      int curIndex=1000, pIndex;

      public DDListAdapter(String[] str, String[] str1) {
          listArray = new ArrayList<DataModelDD>();

          for (int i=0; i < str.length; i++) {
              listArray.add(new DataModelDD(str[i],str1[i], "Dry Day Alert on " + str[i]));   
          }   


      }

      public void DDListUpdate(String[] str, String[] str1){
          listArray = new ArrayList<DataModelDD>();
          for (int i=0; i < str.length; i++) {
              listArray.add(new DataModelDD(str[i],str1[i], "Dry Day Alert on " + str[i]));   
          }   
          this.notifyDataSetChanged();
      }

      @Override
      public int getCount() {
          return listArray.size(); // total number of elements in the list
      }

      @Override
      public Object getItem(int i) {
          return listArray.get(i); // single item in the list
      }

      @Override
      public long getItemId(int i) {

          return i; // index number

      }

      @Override
      public View getView(final int index, View view, final ViewGroup parent) {

          pIndex = index;

          LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
          view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.lstdd, parent, false);

          final DataModelDD dmFl = listArray.get(index);

          final TextView lbl1 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtDDate);
          final TextView lbl2 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtDres);

          lbl1.setText(dmFl.getDDate());
          lbl2.setText(dmFl.getDres());

          final ToggleButton btnDShare = (ToggleButton) view.findViewById(R.id.btnDShare);
          final ToggleButton btnlock = (ToggleButton) view.findViewById(R.id.btnDAlarm);



          btnDShare.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

              @Override
              public void onClick(View v) {
                   if(btnDShare.isChecked()){
                  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                  Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND); 
                  sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");
                  String shareBody = "Dry Day Alert on " + lstMonth.getSelectedItem().toString() + dmFl.getDDate() + " for " + dmFl.getDres();
                  sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "DryDayApp");
                  sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, shareBody);
                  parent.getContext().startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share via"));
              }
              }
          });

          btnlock.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener(){

              @Override
              public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

                  if(btnlock.isChecked()){
                      final String alarmTime = dmFl.getDDate();
                      final String reason = dmFl.getDres();
                      enableAlarm(buttonView,alarmTime,reason);
                      buttonView.setChecked(true);    
                      astatus = true;
                  }
                  else{
                      final String alarmTime = dmFl.getDDate();
                      disableAlarm(buttonView,alarmTime);
                      buttonView.setChecked(false); 
                      astatus = false;
                  }


              }


          });


          return view;
      }
  }
  ```

Comment: what is buttonView and where you declared it?

Answer (score 0):

this may help you...

```
ArrayList<Boolean> toggleOnArr;
public DDListAdapter(String[] str, String[] str1,ArrayList<Boolean> toggleOnArr) {
    listArray = new ArrayList<DataModelDD>();
   this.toggleOnArr = toggleOnArr;
    for (int i=0; i < str.length; i++) {
        listArray.add(new DataModelDD(str[i],str1[i], "Dry Day Alert on " + str[i]));   
    }   


}
```

in public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) method use below given logic..

```
toggleButton.setChecked(toggleOnArr.get(position));
toggleButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {
     if(toggleOnArr.get(position))
      {
         toggleOnArr.set(postion,false); //means first this togglebutton was on but you clicked to make it off

      }else
         toggleOnArr.set(postion,true);

    notifyDataSetChanged();
 }
});
```

Comment: just a silly question is this inteninally  named "Bolean" or it has to be Boolean because this is showing me error

Comment: yourAdapterConstructor(ArrayList<Bolean> toggleOnArr){
 this.toggleOnArr = toggleOnArr;
}  can u plz explain me this  where to declare this and what this code s  doing

Comment: for Customisation of list you must be using a adapter Class, what is its name?

Comment: here i am putting contructor of my adapter class

Comment: toggleButton==btnlock

Comment: do you have values in 'toggleOnArr' when passing to Adapter constructor from activity??

Comment: DDListAdapter(curDts[9], curRes[9],false); i am paasing this

Comment: ArrayList<Boolean> toggleOnArr = new ArrayList<Boolean>(); for(int i=0;i<9;i++){ toggleOnArr.add(false);} DDListAdapter(curDts[9], curRes[9],toggleOnArr);

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51880/discussion-between-naveed-ali-and-user2750762)

Answer (score 0):

The alarm may get overwritten because you may be using the same id for all the alarms, you will have to keep separate ids for each dates.

The checked button gets dissapeared because the listview gets refreshed. You will have to keep the state of the buttons in some array or by some other means to avoid this.